# how to Use NDK in Android

Tags: android

Hi friends I am Using `Ndk` in My Project but while I am building the project got below exception

```
4) Error:(105) undefined reference to 'avcodec_register_all'
Error:(106) undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
Error:(107) undefined reference to 'av_log_set_callback'
Error:(109) undefined reference to 'avformat_alloc_context'
Error:(110) undefined reference to 'av_guess_format'
Error:(120) undefined reference to 'av_new_stream'
Error:(125) undefined reference to 'av_new_stream'
Error:(135) undefined reference to 'avcodec_find_encoder'
Error:(199) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set'
Error:(200) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_int'
Error:(201) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_int'
Error:(202) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_int'
Error:(203) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_int'
Error:(212) undefined reference to 'av_dict_set'
Error:(214) undefined reference to 'av_dict_set'
Error:(215) undefined reference to 'av_dict_set'
Error:(216) undefined reference to 'av_dict_set'
Error:(217) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set'
Error:(218) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set'
Error:(219) undefined reference to 'av_opt_set'
Error:(220) undefined reference to 'avcodec_open2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your app build.gradle file

```
productFlavors{
      x86{
        ndk{
            abiFilter "x86"
           }
        }
enter code here
    armv7a{
        ndk{
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```